# grepl not working with devtools::load_all()

Tags: r, string-matching, devtools, grepl

I have the following function that I have wrappen in a package:

```r
str_grepl <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.table(data)
  data <- data[!grepl("^set", Species)]
  return(data)
}
```

When I run this function and apply the function on my data, it works fine.

```r
library(data.table)

str_grepl(iris)
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#>   1:          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>   2:          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>   3:          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>   4:          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#>   5:          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>   6:          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```

However, when I create a package using RStudio/devtools, save this function and load it with `load_all()` the function does not work:

```r
> str_grepl(iris)
 Error in grepl("^set", Species) : object 'Species' not found
```

The funny thing is that it works if I install the package and load it.

```r
devtools::install()
str_grepl(iris)
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#>   1:          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>   2:          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>   3:          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>   4:          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#>   5:          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>   6:          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```

Any idea why this is?

I have put my example package on Github: https://github.com/filipwastberg/greplpackage

Comment: Could you expand a little more on this? "However, when I create a package using RStudio/devtools, save this function and load it with load_all() the function does not work." I do something similar except I would describe it as saving the function in your "greplpackage" package and then using devtools::load_all() to simulate installing and loading the package.

Comment: Likely you have an object named `Species` visible in your global environment or elsewhere on the search list.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Microsoft R Open, which I am using for the MLK-library. Could it be that Microsoft R Open has an object `Species` in the global environment or somewhere else? What's the best way to check this?

Comment: @akrun I don't think the issue is with data.table.

Answer (score 0):

The issues here was, as @akrun suggested, the description file. After adding:

```
Imports: 
    data.table
```

The issue disappeared:

```
  library(data.table)
  devtools::load_all()
  iris <- iris

str_grepl(iris)
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#>   1:          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>   2:          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>   3:          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>   4:          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#>   5:          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>   6:          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```